# construct confidence interval from proportions

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, estimation

Suppose you have a population of count data, i.e., $1,2,3, \dots, k$, you have a sample of the population of size $n$, and you have a confidence interval for the proportion of $1$'s , $2$'s,\dots$n$'s in the population. Is it possible to construct a confidence interval for the sum of the counts in your sample.

For example,

Suppose you have a sample of size 1000 from a population of count data that can take any value from $1$ to $5$ and the

95% CI for $1$'s is $[.75,.76]$

95% CI for $2$'s is $[.12,.13]$

95% CI for $3$'s $[0.04, .045]$

95% CI for $4$'s is $[.048,.058]$

95% CI for $5$'s is $[.03,.035]$

Can I construct a 95 percent confidence interval for $n\mu$, where $n=1000$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly, yes. For example, take the CI for the proportion of $4$'s.
It is centered at 0.053. If these are the 'usual' kind of CIs used for a sample of size $n=1000,$ then the number of $4$'s in the sample must have been $0.053(1000) = 53$.

In some cases, because the endpoints are rounded,
you will not get an integer answer, but you can come very
close to finding the frequency $f_i$ with which each of the
digits $i$ for $i = 1,\dots,5$ appeared among 1000. 
From that information you can construct a CI based on the whole sample
nearly as well as if you had the original data.

Just what it means to get a CI for the "sum" is unclear.
Ordinarily, in such a situation one would want a CI for the
*population* mean. Maybe your final sentence should have
been "construct a CI for the population mean $\mu$ *based on* the
sum of the counts." (For samples of size $n$, the expected total
would be $n\mu.$  You could get a CI for that.)

Comment: So would my 95% CI look like $x_1+ \ldots +x_{1000} \pm 1.96 ( \sigma \sqrt{n})$

Comment: Sort of. If you're willing to assume normality (by CLT) and if you can estimate $\sigma$. For your data, I'm wondering if the underlying distribution might be Poisson. But as noted. the phrase "confidence interval for the sum of the counts in your sample" simply makes no sense as it stands, so I can only guess at the overall objective.

Comment: Yes, I changed my question to the CI for $n\mu$. I compressed the last 20 data points , i.e. $6, \ldots ,25$ into one point for simplicity. The data behaves more like a negative binomial than a poisson. How do you construct a CI for this kind of data or could I construct a CI with an estimation of $\sigma$ from my data. My sample comes form a population of over 100,000 observations. Could I just use the sd of those points as my estimation of $\sigma$

Comment: For very large sample sizes it's probably OK to assume normality using $\bar X$ and $S.$ For Poisson with total $T$, a pretty good CI is $T + 2 \pm 1.96\sqrt{T + 1}.$ Also, suggest you google "negative binomial confidence interval."

Comment: Is bootstrapping also an option or something I should stay away from. My  sample size is actually 20,000, and it comes from a dataset of 100,000, so I have enough data. I'll also look into the negative binomial CI. Thanks.

Comment: Might be OK. But we're getting off topic now and are about to get busted for doing a chat. Original issue was recovering data from CIs, and I think that has been handled. How about starting a new question on CIs for whatever kind of discrete data you think you have, describing sample size, what parameter to estimate, and what you know about the population.